# jquery append truncated anchor

Tags: jquery, append, anchor

I want append html line with jquery append method

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#favoritos ul").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var drop = '<li><a href="/es/book/marta-5" title="Marta"><img src="/books/5/5_5th.jpg" /></a></li>';
            $(this).append(drop);
        }
    })
})
```

but append this

```
<li><a href="/es/book/marta-5" title="Marta"></a></li>
```

without anchor.
I've tried as anchor text instead of the image but it's truncated too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain? That looks fine. Can you set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate it?

Comment: Code for appending is absolutely correct ,check for any other function on the same page which is affecting the inner html of the anchor tags of that li or ul

Comment: **div #favoritos** and its child elements, are not affected for any other function than drop method of droppable jQuery UI. I'm also, trying to set up entire code: js + css + html on JSFiddle, but it's some complicated to run succesfully.

Comment: I have done a very simple test at [http://jsfiddle.net/TTQDj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/TTQDj/3/) and the anchor is successfully append. The problem must be in the drop function of jQuery UI library, but so far as I know.